# How do I get the articleID and supplierID with the shortest delivery time?

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

I have a SQL table called '**Procurement**':

| ArticleID | SupplierID | DeliveryTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 |
| 1 | 3 | 8 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 | 7 |

I would like to have the supplier with the shortest delivery time for each article:

| ArticleID | SupplierID | DeliveryTime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 3 |

I have problems getting the correct SupplierID:

```
SELECT ArticleID, Min(DeliveryTime) AS DeliveryTime 
FROM Procurement
GROUP BY ArticleID
```

Because of the Group By - clause, the SupplierID column must appear in an aggregation function...

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join your query as a subquery with the table to get the correct SupplierID :

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Procurement p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ArticleID, Min(DeliveryTime) AS DeliveryTime 
  FROM Procurement
  GROUP BY ArticleID
) AS s ON s.ArticleID = p.ArticleID and s.DeliveryTime = p.DeliveryTime
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/XrnWrtxa)

Answer (score 0):

This is the unbiquitous *top(n) per group*, I believe sqlanywhere supports window functions (if you could have ties with multiple Suppliers use *dense_rank*):

```
select ArticleId, SupplierId, DeliveryTime
from (
  select *, 
  Row_Number() over(partition by ArticleId order by DeliveryTime) rn
  from Procurement
)t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and add it in the select. Tested on mysql.

SELECT ArticleID, SupplierID, Min(DeliveryTime) AS DeliveryTime
FROM mytable
GROUP BY ArticleID

[image]